# Listing link between pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to recreate an industrial process by moving pictures of equipment and linking them with arrows to establish the connections and sequence of my process.

I'm able to insert new equipment by clicking on their picture, it copies and pastes the picture, a userform pops up and I set the name of the picture and other parameters.
*Equipment inventory and what it would look like connected*
[image]

I played with some macro to list pictures or shape on the worksheet but I didn't find anything to list the connections.

I know those connections are "recorded" as I recorded a macro that shows it.
*Connection between two pictures*
[image]

How would I list those connections on a worksheet and establish what is connected to what and what comes before what?

Recorded connection

```vb
Sub connection_stack()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("C3")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect ActiveSheet.Shapes("TO1"), 4
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 2.9100441391, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 23.7025647736, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.Flip msoFlipVertical
    Selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect ActiveSheet.Shapes( _
        "Picture 84"), 2
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.4494922067, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.0143200614, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
End Sub
```

*Adding an equipment*
[image]

```vb
Sub New_TO()
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 5")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.OnAction = ""
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 138.4090551181
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -8.1818110236
    Selection.Name = "TO_transit"
    newTO.Show

End Sub
```

*Changing name of equipment from form*
[image]

Once I create new equipment (copy of the pictures with new names) I connect them manually with the arrow that I create and name the same way I do with equipment.

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as a screen capture

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, **never ever** post your code as image. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you, it's working great and allowed me to move foward. If you have any ideas for that part, it would be appreciated.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036227/open-userform-when-i-connect-a-picture-with-a-connector?noredirect=1#comment127285651_72036227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connector is a shape. You just need to loop trough each shape and check if it's a connector with the property Shape.Connector

> [Shape.Connector
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.connector)

As example, I made 3 shapes and 2 connectors:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub test()

Dim kk As Shape
Dim wk As Worksheet


Set wk = ActiveSheet

For Each kk In wk.Shapes
    If kk.Connector = msoTrue Then
        Debug.Print "From ", kk.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.Name, " to ", kk.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Name
    End If
Next kk


End Sub
```

The output I get is exactly how I made my connectors:

```
From          Rectangle 1    to           Oval 2
From          Oval 2         to           Snip Single Corner Rectangle 3
```