# Open userform when I connect a picture with a connector

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I want to open a userform automatically when I connect a picture with a connector (arrow).

When I record the macro for connecting an arrow to a picture I get this code :

```
    Selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect ActiveSheet.Shapes("TO890") _
    , 4
```

So I assume that I could use the "connectorformat.beginconnect" bit. I tried with the following code and it didn't work as I get the "object required" error message.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Shape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect = msoTrue Then 
       newTO.Show 
    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

*edit*
I also tried with this kind of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If selection.Connector = msoTrue And selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect = msoTrue Then
    newTO.Show

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Worksheet_SelectionChange assumes that what is selected is a range (not an object on the sheet). Since you can assign a macro to a shape, that macro might be a better location for your code - if the task you want to do involves clicking the shape...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still need to use the arrow as an arrow so I cant assign it a macro.